# How to do this triple integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a triple integral which is kind of complex, and I want to use Mathematics to help me do the integral. However, when I press "Enter" and "Shift" the software get stuck. I wonder whether this integral cannot be compute?[image]

```
f[x_]:=1/(A-F*x^2+x*B I);
g[y_]:=1/(A-F*y^2+y*B I);
h[z_]:=1/(A-F*z^2+z*B I);
j[x_,y_,z_]:=1/(A-F*(x+y+z)^2-(x+y+z)*B I);
result=Integrate[f[x_]*g[y_]*h[z_]*j[x_,y_,z_],x_,y_,z_]
```

Comment: Your figure is illegible.  Please post copyable code.

Comment: you should not have the underscores in the last expression

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is too complicated for closed form. After fixing your syntax error, and integrating w.r.t. x only, you can see the result contains complex value and very complicated trig functions. Mathematica can't do the integration w.r.t. `y` at this stage

```
f[x_] := 1/(a - c*x^2 + x*b I);
g[y_] := 1/(a - c*y^2 + y*b I);
h[z_] := 1/(a - c*z^2 + z*b I);
j[x_, y_, z_] := 1/(a - c*(x + y + z)^2 - (x + y + z)*b I);
result = Integrate[f[x]*g[y]*h[z]*j[x, y, z], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Integrate[result, y]  (*wait....wait...*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Do you think there is closed form solution for this? Have you considered numerical integration?

Comment: I learnt this from an article that is Non‐Normal Stochastic Response of Linear Systems. This article wants the result as the expression not the numerical value. I want to test and verify this integration whether it is supposed to be right.

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to say the integration limits of this problem. All the upper limits are +infinity, and all the low limits are -infinity.I learnt this from an article that is Non‐Normal Stochastic Response of Linear Systems. This article wants the result as the expression not the numerical value. I want to test and verify this integration whether it is supposed to be right.@Nasser